# How to apply a point transformation to many points?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray, cartopy

I have a gridded temperature dataset and a list of weather stations across the country and their latitudes and longitudes. I want to find the grid points that are nearest to the weather stations. My gridded data has coordinates x,y which latitude and longitude are a function of. [image]

I found that the simplest way of finding the nearest grid point is to first transform the latitude and longitude (`Lat`, `Lon`) of the weather stations to x and y values and then find the nearest grid point. I did that for one station (lat= , lon= ) by doing the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4 as nc

#open gridded data
df=xr.open_dataset('/home/mmartin/LauNath/air.2m.2015.nc')

#open weather station data
CMStations=pd.read_csv('Slope95.csv')

import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Example - your x and y coordinates are in a Lambert Conformal projection
data_crs = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-107.0,central_latitude=50.0,standard_parallels = (50, 50.000001),false_easting=5632642.22547,false_northing=4612545.65137)

# Transform the point - src_crs is always Plate Carree for lat/lon grid
x, y = data_crs.transform_point(-94.5786,39.0997, src_crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Now you can select data
ks=df.sel(x=x, y=y, method='nearest')
```

How would I apply this to all of the weather stations latitudes and longitudes (`Lat`,`Lon`)?

Comment: Use GeoPandas You can extract x and y to create a shapely geometry (same for stations) then use `sjoin_nearest`. You can also use `BallTree` from Scikit-Learn or `KDTree` from SciPy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a geopandas GeoDataFrame from x, y columns using [`geopandas.points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html). I'll assume these points are WGS84/EPSG4326:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

stations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    CMStations,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
        CMStations.Lon, CMStations.Lat, crs="epsg:4326"  # assume WGS84
    ),
)
```

Now, we can use [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) to transform all the points at once:

```py
stations_xy = stations.to_crs(data_crs)
```

Finally, we can use xarray's [advanced indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing), using DataArrays with lat/lon data and station ID as coordinates, to reshape the x/y data to the shape of the CMStations index:

```py
station_x = stations.geometry.x.to_xarray()
station_y = stations.geometry.y.to_xarray()

# use these to select from xarray Dataset ds
station_data = ds.sel(y=station_y, x=station_x, method="nearest")
```

If desired, you could set a station ID column to be the index first with `CMStations.set_index("station_id")` to get the station_id column as the dataset dimension which replaces x and y.

Comment: This works for me but I'm now struggling to apply NearGrid=df.sel(lat=y, lon=x, method='nearest') to the points. I did xy=data_crs.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), Lon, Lat). Then separated the columns into x and y by doing x=xy[:,0]
y=xy[:,1]. But when I then do NearGrid=df.sel(lat=y, lon=x, method='nearest') I get this error "ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['lat', 'lon'] do not exist". How can I use the array of coordinates to find the nearest grid points?

Comment: In my answer I'm selecting using a `DataArray` indexer, not a numpy array. So if you want to pull out joint pairs of `(x, y)` points indexed by station, you need them to be DataArrays with a common index. Also, you're indexing into `x, y`, not `lat, lon`, so the full command should be something like `x=xr.DataArray(xy[:, 0], dims=["station_id"], coords=[CMStations.index])` (or whatever column you want to use as the station ID), then do the same for y, then select with `df.sel(x=x, y=y, method='nearest')`

Comment: Thank you! this worked for me. I appreciate all your help with my questions. Do you know of any good xarray tutorials/online courses?

Comment: honestly I think really getting to know the [advanced indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) section of the docs is a huge factor in xarray expertise. it's makes the difference between being able to subset a cube and being able to flexibly reshape your data however you want :) so I'd give those docs a close read and just play with it for a while! Also, there is an xarray tutorials site in case you haven't seen it: https://tutorial.xarray.dev/intro.html

Comment: also thank *you* - I've actually been meaning to really figure out how to do this sort of bulk crs transformation & selection operation and your questions have pushed me to do just that! haha :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use geopandas in here... just use `crs.transform_points()` instead of `crs.transform_point()` and pass the coordinates as arrays!

```py
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

data_crs = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-107.0,central_latitude=50.0,standard_parallels = (50, 50.000001),false_easting=5632642.22547,false_northing=4612545.65137)

lon, lat = np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3])
data_crs.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), lon, lat)
```

which will return an array of the projected coordinates:

```
array([[16972983.1673108 ,  8528848.37931063,        0.        ],
       [16841398.80456616,  8697676.02704447,        0.        ],
       [16709244.32834945,  8862533.81411212,        0.        ]])
```

---

... also...  if you really have a lot of points to transform (and maybe use some crs not yet supported by cartopy) you might want to have a look at [PyProj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#transformations-from-crs-to-crs) directly since it provides a lot more functionality and also some tricks to speed up transformations. (it's used under the hood by cartopy as well so you should already have it installed!)

Comment: This works for me but I'm now struggling to apply NearGrid=df.sel(lat=y, lon=x, method='nearest') to the points. I did xy=data_crs.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), Lon, Lat). Then separated the columns into x and y by doing x=xy[:,0]
y=xy[:,1]. But when I then do NearGrid=df.sel(lat=y, lon=x, method='nearest') I get this error "ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['lat', 'lon'] do not exist". How can I use the array of coordinates to find the nearest grid points?